# Is there a software that can manage the booklist of what books I have and store it online?

Tags: ebooks, books

I dont want to store every book online since they're easily downloadable.

Comment: What exactly do you want to store? Just a list of ebook titles? Where do you want to store them, anywhere? What kind of formats are they in - .pdf, .mobi, .epub, all kinds of formats? You need to be more specific.

Comment: @Destroy666 yeah just the titles would be fine but it looks a little bit dumb to create a excel file or smth like that just for it. Besides I might want to store more information, such as the edition of the book, which pages I have read up to etc. All file formats are fine.

Comment: @Destroy666 I was too busy to check it recently but I believe you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to do it would be e.g. using [Koodo Reader](https://koodo.960960.xyz/en). By default it backups books, but it generates the backup as .zip file with `books.json`, which you could process either manually or with a script and extract just that file and it contains [this data](https://github.com/troyeguo/koodo-reader/blob/master/src/model/Book.ts).